# I cannot understand how the selector works?

Tags: css

I do not understand how to use the two pseudo-classes. I want to change the black background to the row with cells 3,3,3.

```css
tbody tr:not(:empty):first-of-type td {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Why is background not applicable?

Comment: Im confused as to what you want. If its the row you want why not just `tr:nth-child(4) td`.

Comment: There is no pure CSS solution to obtain the last non empty child. You can use javascript to do this.

Comment: *the row with cells 3,3,3* Based on what criteria? Fourth row from the top? Second row from the bottom? Third non-empty row from the top? First non-empty row from the bottom? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Cells "3" are in the *second to last* row. To select that *second to last* row, you should use `:nth-last-child()` as in:

edit2: `<nope tbody is created as an anonymous element by browsers so you can select`tbody something`without any tbody in a table>` As stated by @Esko in a comment to your question, you don't have a `tbody` element in your HTML code. You should then remove it from the selector. `tr` can only be found in a table so it's unnecessary to add `table` to the left of your selector (but you can).`</nope>`

Note 1: none of your `tr` is/are empty: they contain whitespace and thus are non-empty.
`<tr></tr>` and `<tr><!-- some comment --></tr>`: both empty
`<tr> </tr>`: NOT empty

Note 2: `:first-of-type` would, in your code select the very first `tr`, which is the one with no `td` inside (if it had td children, it'd still be the first of its type)

```css
tr:nth-last-child(2) td {
   background:black;
  }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Number tr unknown

Comment: What do you want to select then? Please add a different use case where what you want to select isn't the second to last row or the fourth row so we can understand. May it have other tr with td after this 4th row or empty ones or right in the middle or empty and non-empty anywhere in any number and I don't have the slightest idea of what you want to select in that case :/

Comment: Actually, he **does** have a `tbody` element. It's not in the HTML, but would be added by the browser. Whether he wants to include it in the selector is another question.

Comment: @torazaburo Indeed, _anonymous element(s)_ which is why the 1st answer by Taha Paksu do select something. Thanks